# How do I populate an array with numbers found in lines of a file?

Tags: perl

There are many solutions on here to similar scenarios as mine, but I can't adapt them to my specific needs.

I have a file where each line contains a name and a list of numbers.  An example line:

Bradley Jones,65,69,71,72,75,71,65,74,69,71,72,75,71,65,65,69,71,72,75,71,65,74,69,71,72,75

How do I add each comma separated piece of data into elements of an array?
The lines could just have a few numbers or have vastly more.  I'd need to know that the first element contained a name and every following element would contain a number, however many were found.

Comment: If that's CSV, just use a CSV parser.

Comment: `split` is a starting point.

Comment: Yes, that will work for me.  I've never used split before, which is why the task looked overly complicated to me.

Comment: Also note `looks_like_number()` in `Scalar::Util` library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt';

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;                   # removes the newline at end of the string
    my @array = split /,/;   # creates the array from the line
    my $name = shift @array; # removes the first element and puts it into $name

    # validate
    say 'Number in first column' if $name =~ /\d/;
    say 'Non-number in remaining columns' if grep { /\D/ } @array;

    # do something with @array
}
```

It turns each line into an array and then takes the first element out of the array and puts it into `$name`. Do something with `@array` before the next line is read. There's some very basic validation which really depends on your use case.

Comment: Thanks for this.  As soon as @Shawn mentioned the split function I could see the solution to my problem.  Without it, I was struggling to conceptualise another way of doing it.

Comment: One slight simplification: `my ($name, @array) = split /,/;`